# How to use publish data over TCP socket instead of UDP

Tags: sockets, tcp, webrtc, pubnub

I have been trying to to use pubnub in order to sent data stream through peers. What is happening though is that the message size on the one side is different from the one the other, though the number of messages sent and received are the same.What i have in mind is that by somehow part of the packets are lost

```
        pubnub.publish({
           channel: 'my_channel',    
           'message' : {  

             'packet':  array_of_packets[counter_array_of_packets], 
              'which_packet_is': counter_array_of_packets,              
               'payload_size': calculate_payload_size('my_channel'array_of_packets[counter_array_of_packets])                                  
           }                   
           callback : function(m){console.log(m)}
        });
            pubnub.subscribe({ 
               channel: 'my_channel',
               message: function(m){wait_(m)},
               uuid: 'Mitsos',
               error: function (error) {
               // Handle error here
               console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
    }
 });
```

The function used to calculate the size is:

```
function calculate_payload_size( channel, message ) {
    return encodeURIComponent(
        channel + JSON.stringify(message)
    ).length + 100;
   }
```

So how can i use the above two functions publish and subscribe in a way that the TCP (reliable transmitting) is used?
(if this can be of any help here is implemented a working example of pubnub - index.html where packets reach the right way the other side, though i can't seem to find if he uses tcp anywhere [link](https://github.com/keyosk/pubnubFileTransfer/blob/master/index.html))

Answer (score 0):

All PubNub client libraries communicate over a TCP socket connection only.
If you are using PubNub JavaScript, Java or Objective-C SDK, then the SDK will take care of Keeping the TCP Socket Connection open for you automatically after you have subscribed to a data channel. This guide on [http-streaming-over-tcp-with-telnet-example](http://www.pubnub.com/community/discussion/14/http-streaming-over-tcp-with-telnet-example) will provide an easy way to use Telnet as an example of Streaming your JSON message payloads over TCP socket.

[image: Stream JSON Messages with Telnet Example]

You can keep a TCP Socket active and alive forever with PubNub's unlimited TTL Socket Session Policy by writing an initial data payload over the socket. After you've established the TCP connection, send an initial payload. Watch this video on [Keeping a TCP Socket Connection Open on your first Network Call](https://vimeo.com/113365702) which walks you through the steps of how to keep a TCP socket connection open.

Comment: So since it is using TCP the amount of data leaving and the amount of data arriving should be the same, correct? (The same applies for the correct turn as which they arrive?)

Comment: Yes, thats right! Can you mail us at support@pubnub.com so we can investigate further?

Comment: Sure, i have already sent an email concerning some cors problems that have appeared and the next one after this will be this if the cors are not responsible for the above problem :)